# How to tell wget to wait for a download countdown

Tags: downloads, wget

I'm currently having some trouble with wget.
I'm trying to download a file but sadly I have to wait 1 minute before I can   access the direkt link or actually download the file.. (i.e.: http://bytefiles.com/rt)

What do I have to do to tell wget to wait for 1 minute and then use the direct link?

I would do it on the Computer I'm currently on but everytime the download hits between 80-90% (I target a 29MB File) it just stops. I hope that wget will handle the download faster & more robust because I have the feeling that I receive some sort of timeout after 10-15 minutes of downloading.

Comment: Add `sleep 60 &&` in front of your `wget` command to have it wait for 60 seconds.

Comment: The direct link which is accessible after 60 seconds changes on each new refresh . :(
I guess I'd have to read it out somehow.. ? Is it possible?

Comment: That can make it tougher, as you would have to find a way to capture the link each time.  I'm probably no help for that one.

Comment: Here is the output I get when I use the sleep 70 && command before wget

http://pastebin.com/qMJEAptc

The direct link is copy pasta from my main machine, so I guess it breaks because my VPS is a different machine. :( EDIT: This is weird, I tried the exact same link on my home machine afterwards and it simply started the download.. so I guess the link is useable for once before it expires? .. Gosh this is so nerve wrecking :/ I hope someone can help me further.

Comment: How about using JDownloader, PhantomJS or Scrapy? ;)

Comment: Well, I know PhantomJS but only from a Python program I coded a while ago. 
Could you maybe give me a few pointers what to do? Sounds like I'd have to code a whole script just for the download. :/
Why does wget even stop after 60kb?!